# Unable to read or post to friends wall (news feed)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have been trying to read a friends news feed to check if my message is there (does not matter if the message is visible, hidden or deleted) and if the message is there, not to post a new message. If it is not there than post a message. The code is below with a lot of unnecessary code to trace where the problem was coming from. I have my permission set for 'publish_stream, read_stream'.

I tried all the code in the other blogs but non seemed to work I do not know whether it is because I am using PHP SDK 3.0 - latest version. My App is iframe app. Even bought an expensive book (too expensive) on Facebook Applications but found out, after buying, that it was out of date!

The code works well if I am using /me or my user id but not my friend's id.

```
require 'config.php';
require 'facebook.php';


//Create facebook application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
  'secret' => $fb_secret
));


$sent = false;
$userData = null;
$PPnotposted = true;
$me = null;
$test_friends =1;

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array("next"=> "<? echo $fb_app_url ?>" ));
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope'=> 'publish_stream, read_stream', 'redirect_uri' => $fb_app_url));
}

$get_someone_else = 100000xxxxxxxxx; // I used a real user id but covered it up here so
                                     my friend's id hidden for this stackexchange help

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    if ( $get_someone_else ){
    $user_profile = $facebook->api("/".$get_someone_else);
    echo "<br/> ********************user is ".$get_someone_else." ******************<br/>";
    var_dump( $user_profile );  
    echo "<br/> ********************** end of user info ******************<br/>";   
    } else {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  }
// print_r( $user_profile );  
$PPaccesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
$attachment[access_token]= $PPaccesstoken ;


    //post message to wall if it is sent through form

    if(isset($_POST['PPmessage'])){
        try {
           if( $get_someone_else ){
          $ppmy_news = $facebook->api("/.$get_someone_else./feed?limit=300");     //Get 300 messages to examine
    echo "<br/> *********************** news feed is ".$ppmy_news." ******************<br/>";
    var_dump( $ppmy_news );  
    echo "<br/> ******************** end of user info ********************<br/>";             
           } else {
          $ppmy_news = $facebook->api('/me/feed?limit=300');  //Get 300 messages 
                                                   //to examine. Initially I set it to
                                                   // 10 messages for testing purposes.
          }


//        var_dump( $ppmy_news);        
//          $sent = $facebook->api("/".$user."/feed", 'POST', $attachment );

          $ppmy_view_lp=0;
          if( $test_friends ) {     //Debugging flag to activate or deactivate parts of code
          echo "sent is :<br />";
//        var_dump( $sent ); 
          echo "<br />";
          $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
          echo "friends is :<br />";
//        var_dump( $friends ); 
          echo "<br />";
                  $friendsLists = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
                  $total_friends = 0;
                  foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) {
                    foreach ($friends as $friend) {
                      $id = $friend['id'];
                      $name = $friend['name'];
                  $total_friends++;  //Get total number of friends
                      echo "friend : ".$name." id is: ".$id." Total friends is : ".$total_friends." <br/> ";
                     }
                  } 
          }
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<br/> !!!!!!!!!!!! Error Dump Line 85 !!!!!!!!!!!!! <br/>";
        var_dump( $e );
        echo "<br/> !!!!!!!!!!!! End of Error Dump !!!!!!!!!!!!! <br/>";        
            //do something about it
        }
    }

}
```

But I find I am denied permission and the catch dump is:

!!!!!!!!!!!! Error Dump Line 85 !!!!!!!!!!!!!
object(FacebookApiException)#2 (7) { ["result:protected"]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(72) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: .100000xxxxxxxxx." ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(803) } } ["message:protected"]=> string(72) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: .100000xxxxxxxxx." ["string:private"]=> string(0) "" ["code:protected"]=> int(0) ["file:protected"]=> string(48) "/home/www/drpetersnews.com/vmt/base_facebook.php" ["line:protected"]=> int(1106) ["trace:private"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(48) "/home/www/drpetersnews.com/vmt/base_facebook.php" ["line"]=> int(810) ["function"]=> string(17) "throwAPIException" ["class"]=> string(12) "BaseFacebook" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(72) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: .100000xxxxxxxxx." ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(803) } } } } [1]=> array(4) { ["function"]=> string(6) "_graph" ["class"]=> string(12) "BaseFacebook" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "/.100000xxxxxxxxx./feed?limit=10" } } [2]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(48) "/home/www/drpetersnews.com/vmt/base_facebook.php" ["line"]=> int(587) ["function"]=> string(20) "call_user_func_array" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> &object(Facebook)#1 (7) { ["appId:protected"]=> string(15) "368XXXXXXXXXX09" ["appSecret:protected"]=> string(32) "eb4216aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfe21" ["user:protected"]=> string(15) "1000000yyyyyyyy" ["signedRequest:protected"]=> NULL ["state:protected"]=> NULL ["accessToken:protected"]=> string(119) "AAAFO5a2SKXkBAAXYgZBdPfTbJKQ3XpBgZBQmU2QcXOx7eo18hB5Hox41J7Of7SMZCj7ZCchJrM1ZCN2KLoAoqCmQWUrjwhDJlMQca005w5kgJIrMQ6ZCdM" ["fileUploadSupport:protected"]=> bool(false) } [1]=> string(6) "_graph" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "/.100000xxxxxxxxx./feed?limit=10" } } } [3]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(40) "/home/www/drpetersnews.com/vmt/index.php" ["line"]=> int(54) ["function"]=> string(3) "api" ["class"]=> string(12) "BaseFacebook" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "/.100000xxxxxxxxx./feed?limit=10" } } } }
!!!!!!!!!!!! End of Error Dump !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Please do help me out and let me know if I have set the permissions wrongly and how to do it properly.

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward: *"Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: .100000xxxxxxxxx"*. Are you sure that this is the right id?

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. Yes the id is correct it is just that I changed it here so that I will not expose my friend's id to general public.

Comment: I understand that, but if you google that specific error message you'll see that usually when people get that message, they used wrong ids.

Comment: I know. I extracted the friends id from the loop in the program and copied and pasted into notebook. I have tried with other friend id but same result. If I use my id it picks up messages in my profile and not in my news feed.

Comment: I have been working on this problem until 4:30am for the past few days then getting up at 8am to carry on. I have seen so many blogs and find none work. Then just now I remembered one blog (God Bless the guy who wrote that blog) mentioned /me/home instead of /me/feed and I just tested it. It picks up from my news feed instead of profile! but it will not pick up from my friends home - still the same error.

Comment: Two things to try: (1) Use the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to check the path you request. (2) You use the user id as an integer (`$get_someone_else = 100000xxxxxxxxx;`), try to use it as a string: `$get_someone_else = '100000xxxxxxxxx';`, maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what Graph Api Explorer was supposed to do until you suggested it. The Graph Api Explorer with 10000030xxxxxx0 comse back with the correct person's name, link,... I tried '100...' as a string instead of 100... but still: "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(803) } } ["message:protected"]=> string(72) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:

Comment: Use a network sniffer (or a network tab in the browser dev tools) to see what the request from facebook is like exactly, from that you can figure out why it fails.

Comment: I don't know what a network sniffer or browser dev tools are. I'm using firefox browser.

Comment: Open firebug, choose the *Network* tab

Comment: I've installed firebug from Mozilla. There is a Net option and showing two ling of info. 1. Get progress-dots.gif and 2. Get comment-help?=1337765559

Comment: I think I did not mention earlier that I can get my friends id, name, first name, last name, hometown, employer, ... but not read his profile or news

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but the problem could lie with Facebook's Privacy Settings. If you can't see the posts on the user's wall, it means that the user has set privacy settings preventing you from seeing the posts.

Use the Graph API Explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and see if you can see the user's feed using it. Check a number of friend IDs to see if any of them return data.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I used the Graph API explorer and when I enter the individual friend id's can see some of their 'connection feed' but cannot see 'connection home' for those that I have tested. But when I use the app I get error mentioned.

Comment: Did you set the application to your app in the Graph API Explorer? By default it uses the Graph API App. See if the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I did make a mistake just now ... I didn't realise I had not set the application to my App. I just set it to my app and 'connection feed' and connection post' return a lot of data for many of my friends, in the Graph API Explorer. But my app does not.

Comment: So it could be privacy settings that are affecting the app or some other permission that you may need in the application. Do you get data for any user IDs? In testing, I was able to see data for some friends, and others not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm clean up my code and removing all debug info and than I will go back to trace this issue